# Pytorch error when modifying unpacked tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have an error when modifying an unpacked tensor.

```
import torch
a1, a2 = torch.tensor([1,2], dtype = torch.float64)
b = torch.rand(2, requires_grad = True)

a1 += b.sum()
```

This code produces the following error:

```
RuntimeError: A view was created in no_grad mode and is being modified inplace with grad mode enabled. This view is the output of a function that returns multiple views. Such functions do not allow the output views to be modified inplace. You should replace the inplace operation by an out-of-place one.
```

However, I didn't receive that error when I created a1 and a2 separately as follows:

```
a1 = torch.tensor([1], dtype = torch.float64)
a1 += b.sum()
```

I have no idea why unpacking a tensor would lead to that error. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is clear and explains that:

- You created two views a1 and a2 in `no_grad mode` and view b in `grad mode enabled`.
- Such functions (unpacking) do not allow the output views (a1,a2) to be modified inplace (inplace operation +=)
- **Solution:** you should replace the inplace operation by an out-of-place one. You can clone `a1` to `a` before this operation as follows:

  ```
  a = a1.clone()
  a += b.sum()
  ```

That is because tensor.clone() creates a copy of the original tensor with `requires_grad` field. Thus, you will find now `a` and `b` have `requires_grad`. If you print the

```
print(a.requires_grad)        #True
print(b.requires_grad)        #True
print(a1.requires_grad)       #False
```

You can read more about inplace operation [1](http://www.ilduf.org/pytorch-inplace) [2](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/leaf-variable-was-used-in-an-inplace-operation/308/2?u=elqadasi)